# jQuery load data-targets not persisting

Tags: jquery, html

I have a `navbar.html` that includes some toolbar functionality.

I am loading it into a div on another page `$("#nav-bar").load("nav-bar.html")`

Inside `nav-bar.html` there are links with `data-targets` set:

`<a role="button" data-target="#panelOverlays" aria-haspopup="true">`

The data-target functionality is not working when I load the html, but works fine statically.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I think data-attributes are only set when the page first loads. So if you're dynamically loading html into the page `$(selector).data('target')` won't work.  Use`$(selector).attr('data-target')` instead as this should work with dynamically loaded stuff.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox Thanks for the reply.  `data-target` called in bootstrap libraries, not my code.  I can't change this.

Comment: You may need to call the bootstrap function that iniitalizes the navbar after you reload it.

Comment: Quite.  Something like: `$('#nav-bar').navbar();`

Comment: @Barmar Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since `bootstrap.js` was binding the data-attributes, including it after the load worked.  Thanks everyone.

This is what I ended up doing:

```
<script>
$("#nav-bar-container").load("nav-bar.html", function() {

  var script = document.createElement( "script" );
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "../libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.js";
  $("body").append(script);
});
</script>
```